# Github Personal Access Token. Error fatal: not in a git directory

Tags: git, github, rstudio, token, git-credential-manager

I'm trying to use my github personal access token in RStudio.

When I try to run
`$ git config credential.helper store` I get the error "fatal: not in a git directory." I've tried creating a new project and intializing it as a git repository but it gives me the same error. I've also tried cloning a repository, but it just gives me the error that I need to set up a token.

How can I solve this problem so I can store my access token and clone repositories?

Comment: Tried adding `--global`? Or running `git init` then `cd`-ing into the repo and then setting the credential manager?